# show div when form file upload browse button is clicked or when a file is selected and input?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to show a div only when the user selects and image by clicking the file upload browse button. can someone please show me where i am going wrong and how to get this to work, i am using this html code:

```
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" onClick="showSubmit(this);"/>
```

my js code:

```
<script>
  function showSubmit(submit) {
      document.getElementById("submit").style.display = submit.checked ? "block" : "none";

  }
</script>
```

my div html:

```
<div id="submit">
<div id="content2">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form> 
</div>
</div>
```

my div css:

```
#submit{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read this: http://viget.com/inspire/custom-file-inputs-with-a-bit-of-jquery

Comment: what is this? submit.checked???

Comment: `submit.checked` doesn't make sense. It's not a checkbox, it's a submit button; there's no such property as `checked` on a submit button. Perhaps providing a bit more detail on what you're trying to accomplish would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .submitClass {
        display: none;
    }
    .displaySubmit{
        display:block;
        height:20px;
        text-align:center;
        padding:2px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSubmit(submit) {
        document.getElementById("submit").className = "displaysubmit";
    }
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" onclick="showSubmit(this);" />
<div id="submit" class="submitClass">
    <div id="content2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using **jQuery**:

```
  $(function() {
     $("input:file").change(function (){
       var fileName = $(this).val();
       $(".filename").html(fileName);
     });
  });
```

If you're using **pure javascript**, just use the onchange event of your input field.